# Make jQuery to discard an action for a particular div class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I wrote a jQuery (function) to perform an action for certain div-class(A). When we click the hyperlinks within that div class, those links will be opened in another div-id(B). Here, my issues is : I want to disable the function for one link with in the first div class(A).

For example, if there are two hyperlinks in the div-class(A) (for suppose 1 and 2) when we click the link 1, it should execute the jQuery. When we click the link 2, the jquery should not be executed for that link.
NOTE: the two links (link1 and link2 both are in the same div-class(A)).

my jQuery function goes as

```
$('.div-class(A) a').click(function(){
var url = $(this).attr('href');
var height = $('#div-id(B)').height();
var width = $('#div-id(B)').width();
$('#div-id(B)').replaceWith( "'<object data="+url+" width="+width+" height="+height+"/>'" );
return false;
});
```

How should I handle this issue. Do I need to add disable function?? Obviously, I shouldn't use .remove() -> as completely removes the link.

Any Suggestions???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use `.on()` to bind your event then you could unbind it with `.off()`, like so:

Updated to reflect OPs actual needs (I think)

```
$('.div-class(A) a').on('click', function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var height = $('#div-id(B)').height();
    var width = $('#div-id(B)').width();

    $('#div-id(B)').replaceWith( "'<object data="+url+" width="+width+" height="+height+"/>'" );

    return false;
});

// This will unbind the click action for a tags inside a div with id #sub-b
$('#sub-b a').off('click');
```

One thing to note, if you use event delegation, then you can't use off on an inner div in this way.

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyface/VpGE6/)

[see jQuery off documentation](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Comment: let me be clear, there is main div-class(A) in that I have two sub-classes namely - div-class(a) & div-class(b). now the query should execute for the div-class(a) and not for the div-class(b). the links in the div-class(b) should work normally, but the links in the div-class(a) should perform the query action.

Comment: And don't ask me " why can't you specify only div-class(a) (subclass) rather than the div-class(A) (main class)????". It's my requirement..

Comment: haha, I won't, I understand sometime you just have to do something a certain way.

Comment: I can't really understand from your explanation what effect you're trying to achieve, sorry. Can you link to a demo of the functionality you have?

Comment: right now I can't show the demo but I'll explain you clearly, suppose we have a class(div-A) let me show you this

Comment: div-A{ div-a; div-b }

Comment: div-a has a number of links (stackoverflow.com, etc...) whereas div-b has a link named more (more - is a link which redirects to the our site )

Comment: with my jQuery, the function is applicable to the whole div class (div-A, both for the links div-a and div-b). but I want to apply the jQuery only for the div-a..

Comment: Ok, I think I get it now having built this demo from your description

http://jsfiddle.net/andyface/VpGE6/

Essentially what it's doing is binding the click for a tags in the main div #A and then unbinding the click for a tags under #sub-b

does this do what you need it to and in the way that you have to do it?

Comment: wowww, on('click',funtion())::: that was a great solution. I never tried it and even never thought in such a perspective. Thank you @andyface for your brilliant solution.

Comment: @gimibarak no problem, glad I could help. I've been using .on() for a while as it provides a lot more versatility than the .click() function

Answer (score 0):

Try

> :not selector

```
$('.div-class(A) a:not(disabledLinkSelctor)').click(function(){
var url = $(this).attr('href');
var height = $('#div-id(B)').height();
var width = $('#div-id(B)').width();
$('#div-id(B)').replaceWith( "'<object data="+url+" width="+width+" height="+height+"/>'" );
return false;
});
```

Comment: what is disabledLinkSelctor here?? is it the some section of the div-class, which i dont want to perform the action???

Comment: i tested with inner div-class within the main div-class(A). It doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the event once it has been clicked the first time then you can just unbind it:

```
$('.div-class(A) a').click(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var height = $('#div-id(B)').height();
    var width = $('#div-id(B)').width();
    $('#div-id(B)').replaceWith( "'<object data="+url+" width="+width+" height="+height+"/>'" );
    $(this).off("click");
    return false;
});
```

For more details on off: [http://api.jquery.com/off/](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

If you just want certain links in your div to be clickable just add an appropriate class and filter by it:

```
$('.div-class(A) a.opensUpDivB').click(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var height = $('#div-id(B)').height();
    var width = $('#div-id(B)').width();
    $('#div-id(B)').replaceWith( "'<object data="+url+" width="+width+" height="+height+"/>'" );
    return false;
});
```

Comment: it's a class you give to the link which should open up div B

Comment: also have a look at this event binding: http://api.jquery.com/one/ only executes the first time! might be perfect